# Django custom management commands: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Command'

Tags: django

I am trying to make a custom management command as show in the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

When I try to run the command from my project directory I am experiencing the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Command'
```

Here is the file:

```
#event_expiration.py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from app.models import Event
import datetime

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'deletes expired events'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        events = Event.objects.filter(date=datetime.date(2011,11,11))

        for e in events:
            e.delete()

        self.stdout.write('Expired events successfully deleted.')
```

The command I am running is :

```
$ python manage.py event_expiration
```

I've made sure I am adding the event_expiration.py file within management and commands folders and that those folders have init files. those are in one of my app folders.

Am I overlooking something here? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:

Fellow SO user Yuji helped me attempt to debug this a bit but we are still stumped. heres what we did:

First, the full traceback and command:

```
(venv)matt@inspirion14z:~/Dropbox/PROD/ersvp.it$ python manage.py event_expiration
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/matt/Dropbox/PROD/ersvp.it/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/matt/Dropbox/PROD/ersvp.it/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/matt/Dropbox/PROD/ersvp.it/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/matt/Dropbox/PROD/ersvp.it/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 70, in load_command_class
    return module.Command()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Command'
```

To see what was going on at django/core/management/**init**.py", line 70 I placed import pdb; pdb.set_trace() within the file.

While in debug mode we tried:

```
module.__file__
```

to check if the module was where expected, and it indeed was, with an output of:

```
'/home/matt/Dropbox/PROD/ersvp.it/app/management/commands/event_expiration.pyc'
```

Next, we tried manually importing Command in the shell:

```
>>> from app.management.commands.event_expiration import Command 
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<console>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: cannot import name Command
```

Still scratching my head!

Comment: Is the app this is in within INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py?

Comment: You should post the debugging we did: it's a big hint what errors you got trying to import the Command from the shell

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's problem, but for anyone landing here, make sure your class name is actually `Command` and not `YourCustomCommand`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is your file structure like? It should be like so:

```
app/
    __init__.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            event_expiration.py
```

If the structure is as above, try the following:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from app.management.commands import event_expiration
>>> dir(event_expiration)
['Account', 'BaseCommand', 'Callback', 'Command', 'CommandError', 'Comment', 'Status', 'User', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'clean_phone_number', 'csv', 'models', 'os', 're']
```

I've listed the pure output of running `dir` on a management command of my own. Give that a try, and report back what is available to the module. You might find yourself getting an error at this point, which *may* help diagnose. I'm suspecting a problem with importing django itself. I'm guessing the `python manage.py shell` will fail, which will mean it's not a problem with your command, but a problem with the project.

Edit 2:

The fact that `check_expiration` was visible in your `dir` output supports my theory that the folder structure is amiss in someway. Unless there's specifically a function named that within your module.

Please do the following and show the output:

```
cd /path/to/app/
find .
```

Also, show the entire contents of your `event_expiration.py` file, and the contents of your `management/commands/__init__.py` file. Be wary of spaces mixed with tabs as whitespace also.

Comment: Hi Josh, yes this is the file structure. I am running the command from my project directory.

Comment: The above commands execute fine Josh, the output is like so: ['Event', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'check_expiration', 'datetime']

Comment: @mwmnj, `check_expiration` seems like a weird thing to be available.. Where is check expiration defined? There's something wrong with your folder structure, or folder structure according to python. Is anything defined in your `__init__` files that could be affections this?

Comment: Geeze, turns out I had two different event_expiration.py files and was editing the one located in my main project directory. :X Thanks for the help, I need to be more careful!

Comment: @mwmnj glad you figured it out! I find it funny that you went to the lengths of using pdb, and the actual issue was so much simpler. Isn't our work funny sometimes :P

Comment: Yes! at least now I know how to use pbd if a real bug comes along!

Answer (score 36):

I ran into the same issue and the problem was that my command class wasn't called exactly `Command`, as the docs says. Example:

```
class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    # Do something here
```

Comment: Fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This fixed the issue, but where does it say that in the docs? I can't find it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: `it must define a class Command that extends BaseCommand or one of its subclasses`

Answer (score 0):

**Printing a queryset directly will also cause this error**. For instance, I was trying to do something like this (just testing, not a real use case):

```
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
       ppl = People.objects.all()
       print(ppl)
```

**Resolution**:

```
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
       ppl = People.objects.all()
       print(str(ppl)) # Convert queryset to string
```

**Conclusion**: What works in shell doesn't necessarily work in a management command. Would be nice if someone can point out why.

Answer (score -1):

I got this error by importing the regular click module instead of `djclick`

`my_module/management/commands/run_thing.py`

```
# import click  # causes the error because not setup like djclick is
import djclick as click

@click.command()
@click.option("--thing", required=True, prompt=True)
def command(thing):
    print(f"hi: {thing}"
```

Example run:

```
./manage.py run_thing --thing 123
...
hi: 123
```